# How to retrieve an image and display it in grid view?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Following is the schema of table council_member
Council_member(Email, Name, Contact, Gender, Picture, Team, Dept, Society);
I am using a grid view and then retrieving all the data through SQL data source. But the problem is that picture is not being displayed. 
Here is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Email" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" SortExpression="Contact" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" SortExpression="gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Dept" HeaderText="Dept" SortExpression="Dept" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Society" HeaderText="Society" SortExpression="Society" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Webappconstring %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Webappconstring.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM council_member"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

so, whats the syntax to retrieve and display image(in any format)?
PS: Im a newbie

Comment: What c# code have you found so far to attempt this?

Comment: I haven't used any because Im totally blank at this. Do you know of any tutorial that I could take help from?

Answer (score 0):

Following link might help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx